# How do we name the files that are streamed via firehose?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm building an architecture using boto3, and I hope to dump the data in JSON format from API to S3. What blocks in my way right now is first, firehose does NOT support JSON; my workaround right now is not compressing them but it's still different from a JSON file. **But I still want to see a better choice to make the files more compatible.**
[image]

And second, the file names can't be customized. All the data I collected will be eventually converted onto Athena for the query, so can **boto3 do the naming**?

Comment: Its not clear what do you mean by not supporting json?

Comment: @Marcin Compression for data records

Comment: Sorry, but its still unclear. Firehose does not do any comparison, thus it does not care if the that is JSON or not. It can work with any format.

Comment: I made some edits in the description. I meant the file format in the destination doesn't include JSON.

Comment: JSON isn't in that list of compression formats because JSON is not a compression format.

Comment: Okay, it's fine. I'm actually more concerned about the naming issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answering a couple of the questions you have.  Firstly if you stream JSON into Firehose it will write JSON to S3.  JSON is the file data structure and compression is the file type.  Compressing JSON doesn't make it something else.  You'll just need to decompress it before consuming it.

RE: file naming, you shouldn't care about that.  Let the system name it whatever.  If you define the Athena table with the location, you'll be able to query it.  When new files are added, you'll be able to query them immediately.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis-agent-windows/latest/userguide/directory-source-to-s3-tutorial.html) is an AWS tutorial that walks you through this process.  JSON stream to S3 with Athena query.

Comment: Sounds good! But to be more specific, I think what I'm streaming is a dict because I use python (boto3). So the question is, is it possible to convert this dict to a json via firehose?

Comment: You can use json.dumps(dictionary) to convert the python dict to json string before putting the record on the stream.